# Update RSS from another XML file?

Tags: asp.net, xml, rss

Hey. I am quite new to the whole web development/programming. I am trying to create an RSS feed which gets info from a separate XML file.

I know basics about XML and RSS, but I don't know how to make it updade. Lets say I update the XML then how would the RSS update automatically? Can someone maybe put me on the right track? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show an example of the input XML and the desired output RSS?

Comment: <File>
<Row>
<Column Name="Job Code">blah blah blah</Column>
<Column Name="# of Positions">blah blah blah</Column>
<Column Name="Justification (Text Only)"/>
<Column Name="Reason"/>
<Column Name="TE Job Title">blah blah blah</Column>
<Column Name="Purpose (Text Only)">blah blah blah</Column>
<Column Name="Requirement (Text Only)">blah blah blah</Column>
<Column Name="Responsibities (Text Only)">blah blah blah</Column>
</Row>
</File>
I know it is a very badly designed xml but thats what ive been given. Rss?jsut a standart one,so when we update XML it would update rss as wel. thanx

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In which programming language do you want to accomplish this? One way would be to run a program that does some XML parsing and writing, e.g. PHP with [SimpleXML](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and running the script as a cronjob.</strike>

**[Edit:]**
You could use LINQ to XML for that in ASP.NET, it is easy to use, just look at tutorials like [Using LINQ to XML](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/07/using-linq-to-xml-and-how-to-build-a-custom-rss-feed-reader-with-it.aspx) or 

[Introduction to LINQ - Simple XML Parsing](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/introduction-to-linq-simple-xml-parsing)

Comment: ive been told to use asp.net..i am just trying to get my mind on the right truck.xml parsing and writing?that might work..thanx